Tldraw Collaboration: Eraser Changes Not Syncing Across Users Using Socketio
I’m building a collaborative drawing application using Tldraw and socket.io. The goal is to allow multiple users to draw and erase shapes, and their changes should sync in real time. While drawing shapes is working fine, erasing and syncing changes across users isn't functioning as expected.
Here’s what I’m currently doing:
Emit Local Changes:
Whenever a user makes changes (drawing or erasing), I emit a DRAWING_UPDATE event with the snapshot data using getSnapshot(editor.store).
const handleChangeEvent = useCallback(() => {
    if (editor) {
      const snapshot = getSnapshot(editor.store);
      console.log("Snapshot being emitted:", snapshot);
      if (snapshot && typeof snapshot === "object") {
        setDrawingData(snapshot);
        socket.emit("DRAWING_UPDATE", { snapshot });
      } else {
        console.error("Invalid snapshot during change event:", snapshot);
      }
    }
  }, [editor, setDrawingData, socket]);

Handle Remote Changes:
When a user receives a DRAWING_UPDATE event, I process the added, updated, and removed records in the snapshot to update the local editor store.
const handleRemoteDrawing = useCallback(
  ({ snapshot }) => {
    if (!snapshot || typeof snapshot !== "object") {
      console.error("Invalid snapshot data:", snapshot);
      return;
    }

    const { added = {}, updated = {}, removed = {} } = snapshot;

    if (editor) {
      editor.store.mergeRemoteChanges(() => {
        // Adding/updating shapes
        Object.values({ ...added, ...updated }).forEach((record) => {
          if (record && record.typeName === "shape") {
            editor.store.put([record]);
          }
        });

        // Handling deletions
        Object.keys(removed).forEach((id) => {
          if (editor.store.has(id)) {
            editor.store.remove(id);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  },
  [editor]
);

Lifecycle Management:
I listen for changes in the local editor and emit them using Socket.IO.
I load initial data for the editor using loadSnapshot
useEffect(() => {
  if (editor && drawingData) {
    loadSnapshot(editor.store, drawingData);
  }
}, [editor, drawingData]);

Problem:
Erasing Shapes: Deleted shapes are not being removed on other users' screens.
Expected Behavior:
When a user erases a shape, it should disappear from other users' editors.
Actual Behavior:
erasers  updates are not visible to other users.
Question:
How can I ensure that  erasing actions are synced across all users in real time using Tldraw and Socket.IO?
For drawing everything is fine.

there are a few moving parts here, you need to troubleshoot where is the problem. Maybe we are not getting the "remove" message ... have you tried putting some console log in the Object.keys(removed).forEach ?

Do you have a minimal but complete example? ... with the code you provided I see no way to reproduce this
